# why just putchar the 1st character of character string?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
  int c;
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
    if(c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n'){
      putchar('\n');
    }
    else
      putchar(c);
  }
}
```

why just putchar the 1st character of character string?

Comment: This program doesn't just `putchar` the first character of the [input] string, there's a loop.

Comment: thx very much, I ran again, this time is OK.

Answer (score 2):

The `putchar()` is preceded by a `getchar()` -- they're being used as a pair, so for every single character received as input, one character is being sent to output.